# NVIDIA GEFORCE Driver do not work properly?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have NVIDIA **GEFORCE 840m** GPU. It's compilable **version is 353.30**. When I install that driver, it installed but not working. In driver, it shows a message "**Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)**". I am using Windows 10 & it's updated.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually according to Nvidia the only version for your card is 390.77: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/130637/en-us . Try installing that version and if the installer gives the option the remove previous settings, use it.

Comment: Use imgur, your image website, doesn’t work for me.  Edit your question

Comment: @Ramhound https://imgur.com/a/ZUXsr .

Comment: I already try this one. But it says, it's not compatible with hardware. Screenshort: https://imgur.com/a/2cE55

Comment: Does the driver you first used specifically support Windows 10, if it does not, then Windows 10 cannot be used on that machine

Comment: I am facing this issue since yesterday. Currently, no fix. It is a Windows 10 issue for sure, since all is working just fine under Windows 8.1. You can try to install newer or older drivers but for that you need first to enter safe mode, use Dispaly Driver Uninstaller https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-v17083-released, reboot and reinstall display drivers. Hope that works.

Comment: @MichaelBay, tried that, did not work.

Comment: I used windows 10 on this machine before. It has core i7 processor, @Ramhound

Comment: Doesn’t answer my question.  Does the driver you installed specifically support Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound yes. It supports Windows 10. I used it before on this machine.But it's not working right now.

Comment: SOLVED, couple of days a go I had installed a software for a UPS (attached to UPS by USB). I simply un-installed that software and restarted Windows Problem Gone.